# Why is iterating through a string more expensive than splitting it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance

I am writing some code that needs to iterate through each character of input. I've found that the following loop is several times more expensive on my (large) input file than the one below it

```
s = sys.stdin.read()
for i in range(len(s)):
    pass

for c in sys.stdin.read().split('\n'):
    pass
```

I am perplexed as to how split can be more efficient than simply iterating through the string. If anyone could provide insight I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: for one thing, because iterating through the string creates a bunch of new string objects on each iteration for every character, split creates less numbers of new strings (usually).

Comment: The first iterates by character, the second by line. The first loop probably simply iterates several orders of magnitudes more often.

Comment: Note, `for line in sys.stdin: ...` should be faster than `for line in sys.stdin.read().split('\n')`

Comment: @deceze Integrates? Do you mean iterates? My question is really about how split managed to find all newlines in the string (which must require a complete traversal) faster than I can iterate through it once. The second one should theoretically involve at least as many operations as the first.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I don't think this is the case. Even iterating over the length of the string is slower. I have updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: Highly optimized C code vs. userland Python loop. That’s quite a difference.

Comment: @curious why do you expect `range(len(s))` to be faster? It will make much more iterations.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga split must traverse the entire string internally, so the run time analysis should be O(n).

Comment: @curious yes, so what? it *is* O(N). All of these are O(N).

Comment: @deceze I have a hard time believing that python is slow enough not to interpret a simple loop like 'for i in range(len(s))' in a sane way.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The first one is an order of magnitude slower in practice.

Comment: @curious what do you mean by "sane"? A python iterator-based for-loop is going to be *significantly* slower than any lower-level C-loop over a raw string buffer. And yes, that isn't surprising. Optimized built-in methods are *significantly* faster than anything you do at an interpreter-level for-loop.